# c: issue with strchr(): returning wrong value?

Tags: c

I'm trying to do some code stuff within `strchr` but unfortuantly my use of `strchr` was leading to execution bugs, it appears that `strchr` in some cases returning wrong value,
here is the code:

```
int main(){

    char* s="1/2/3/4/8/9/7";
    char r[100];
    char chunk2[100];
    int i,jpos;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    strcpy(r, strrev(s));
    jpos = strchr(r, '/')-r;
    strncpy(chunk2, r, jpos);
    strcpy(r, strrev(chunk2));
    }
}
```

what's wrong? and how can I fix the issue? thanks.

Comment: What result do you expect? What result are you getting?

Comment: it was a very big integer value: wrong value, overflow like. but it's solved now.

Comment: Random tip: If you think your compiler or library is wrong, 99.999% of the time you are mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

s is a string literal, strrev() tries to change it, you cannot do that on static data.

Use an array of characters

```
char s[]="1/2/3/4/8/9/7";
```